# How can i pass a struct method as callback in Rust?

Tags: rust

In C++, I work with this.

```cpp
class A{
    public:
        void read();
}

class B{
    public:
    void setCallback(std::function<void()> f){
        ...
    }
}

int main(){
    A a;
    B b;
    b.setCallback(std::bind(&A::read,&a));
}
```

Could I implement the same function in Rust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@isaactfa answer is correct, but `std::function` uses dynamic dispatch and is more like `Box<dyn Fn()>` than using generics.

```rust
struct B<'a> {
    callback: Option<Box<dyn FnMut() + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn set_callback(&mut self, callback: Box<dyn FnMut() + 'a>) {
        self.callback = Some(callback);
    }

    fn call_callback(&mut self) {
        self.callback.as_mut().map(|cb| cb());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A { x: 0 };
    let mut b = B { callback: None };
    b.set_callback(Box::new(|| a.do_something()));
    b.call_callback();
    drop(b); // It is necessary for the code to not use `a` while it's borrowed by the closure
    assert_eq!(a.x, 1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bfb43feb25e18a352c4c6ad08f5d5fd9).

You can have a little more convenience by creating the `Box` within the struct methods, so the caller doesn't have to create it:

```rust
impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn set_callback(&mut self, callback: impl FnMut() + 'a) {
        self.callback = Some(Box::new(callback));
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fcefc1c9b55c27a5e7c0b7750f4c7c7b).

Comment: okay, thx. I'll try it. It looks like what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
struct A {
    x: u32,
}

impl A {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        self.x += 1;
    }
}

struct B<F> {
    callback: Option<F>,
}

impl<F: FnMut()> B<F> {
    fn set_callback(&mut self, callback: F) {
        self.callback = Some(callback);
    }
    
    fn call_callback(&mut self) {
        self.callback.as_mut().map(|cb| cb());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A { x: 0, };
    let mut b = B { callback: None, };
    b.set_callback(|| a.do_something());
    b.call_callback();
    assert_eq!(a.x, 1);
}
```

I took a conservative guess at what the mutability requirements would be.